# How to print precise digits after E in scientific notation in c++

Tags: c++11

the output of the code is  1.068950000E+002 instead the required output is 1.068950000E+02

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double c=106.895;
   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(9)<<std::scientific<<C<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the number of digits of the outputted exponent in scientific notation using the standard manipulators in C++.

One thing you could do is to remove or add a `'0'` to the resulting string, if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    double c = 106.895;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.setf(std::ios_base::scientific | std::ios_base::uppercase);
    ss << std::setprecision(9) << c;
    auto number = ss.str();

    // you can add the '0' if needed
    size_t pos = number.size() - 3;
    if ( !std::isdigit(int(number[pos])) )
    {
        if ( number[pos] == 'E' )
            number.insert(pos + 1, "+0");
        else
            number.insert(pos + 1, 1, '0');
    }

    std::cout << number << '\n';  // --> 1.068950000E+002

    // Or remove it
    size_t pos_0 = number.size() - 3;
    if ( number[pos_0] == '0' )
        number.erase(pos_0, 1);
    std::cout << number << '\n'; // --> 1.068950000E+02
}
```

Comment: It was a question in hacker rank under c++ language. Their compiler is showing error due to this .

Comment: @SakshiSinghal Could you please elaborate on that? Is it the compiler or the online judge which gave you an error?

Comment: its a compiler. Isn't there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: @SakshiSinghal In the question you mention a specific format issue of some output values which may be solved using one of the methods I showed. Now you are talking about a compiler error (which would cause the compilation to stop, so no program to run and therefore no output). What error? What compiler and with what flags? What Hacker Rank problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Because of the wrong output I was unable to submit the code of the question given in the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/prettyprint/problem

Comment: My code For the above problem is given below:-                                       int f;
        f=A;
        cout<<setw(2)<<"0x"<<hex<<f<<endl;

   //<<showpos<<ios::right
        cout<<setw(15)<<setfill('_')<<right<<showpos<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<B<<endl;

        cout<<noshowpos<<fixed<<setprecision(9)<<std::scientific<<C<<endl;

Comment: @SakshiSinghal I passed all the tests with `cout << noshowpos << scientific << uppercase << setprecision(9) << C << '\n';`. Are you sure that the error is in that line (and not in the A output)?